# Generic baking error on main

Tags: baking, error

I need help with a baking error. I originally posted on slack but was asked to post here as well. 
Has anyone seen this issue? I have been missing many endorsements and baking with the following generic error:

```
Feb 9 12:57:53 - client.scheduling: Error while baking:<br>
Feb 9 12:57:53 - client.scheduling: Error:<br>
Feb 9 12:57:53 - client.scheduling:  Unregistred error:<br>
Feb 9 12:57:53 - client.scheduling:   { "kind": "generic",<br>
Feb 9 12:57:53 - client.scheduling:    "error":<br>
Feb 9 12:57:53 - client.scheduling:     "Error while applying operation ooPMZTsQzPi1g89rSswe1Rx <br>
```

I tried on two different machines with 2 (updated) ledgers nano s and updated baking apps. I can miss 20 in a row and then start baking again. I tried isolating the issue but I can't affect or control whether I am missing baking/endorsements or not. 
Things I tried/checked based on feedback:

- reauthorize the ledger after updating
- have enough bond
- delegation stake hasen't really changed since I started. the bakery has 2 rolls available for bond and about 20 rolls delegated to it.
- tripled checked my network during endorsement and baking
- I know that the error occurs at the beginning of the baking process. The error displays itself immediately.

Baking/endorsing restarts or stops without any of my actions triggering it.

Comment: What about time ? Is the time correctly set on your computer ?

Comment: Yes, the time is correct, thanks. I feel like such a noob.  I thought I understood the bond calculations, but I guess I didn't.  As a baker I am staking 2 rolls with 21 rolls delegated towards my bakery.  Based on these values I thought that I was able to satisfy the bonds requirements.  Anyway...I need to do some reading.  One thing that confuses me on tzscan is that my "funds required" are red, but yet now I am no longer missing endorsing and baking. 
Thanks everyone.

Comment: can you post an answer to your question? maybe with some details of things related to bonds that you now understand better?

Comment: Also linking an answer to the bond calculation that was provided by Ezy: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/456/security-deposit-calculation/457#457

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bond computation (% of tokens you need for a given number of rolls) is not exact, it depends on how many rolls are actually used for baking, and also of what happen on the network:

- the mean percentage is computed by supposing that all rolls are activated and used for baking. Given that, you can compute how often you bake for one roll, and how much deposit you need. Yet, currently, not all rolls are used, so you are chosen more often and you need more deposit;
- TzScan displays what you need for the next cycles, computed this time using the real baking rights at slot 0. Yet, some bakers may not take their turn and your baker can steal slots, needing this more deposit (with 24 rolls, not very often...)

For now, TsScan is probably the most reliable source, the required xtz for the cycle should never be red.