# Do minimum funds for baking include delegated funds?

Tags: solo-baking

Currently 10k XTZ are required for baking. If me and my friends combined to have 10k, can they delegate their portion to me and I will be able to bake? Or do I need to own at least 10k myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained here

https://medium.com/tezos/liquid-proof-of-stake-aec2f7ef1da7

The minimum staking balance for baking is 1 roll which includes the baker *plus* delegated funds.

So the answer to your question is: yes

To further the minimum capital the baker need to have in order to operate on normal conditions under the current protocol (003) is the *security deposit* aka *bond*. Aspects of the calculation of the bond are detailed here

https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/1056/118

And

https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/457/118